# which GUI tool and language makes these customized title bar(or Frame) on windows?

Tags: windows, python, gui, graphic-design, gui-builder

I saw a program interface with a customized title bar.

[image]

I have few experiences of GUI programming. My major language is python, so I have made a few of program with wxpython library(same with wxWidgets in C++). But in my knowledge, pure python can make these customized GUI. Which GUI tool and language makes these customized title bar(or Frame) on windows ? Even the program in the capture image turn on light when on mouse over the top-right side buttons. Amazing in my poor knowledge and experience

More information about my need:

- I am a preliminary learner for GUI programming and willing to learn any languages and tools.
- The OS platform I want my programs to run on is windows.
- .net framework(C#) and wxpython gives us easy way to make "forms". But I want to make my customized form(Frame, Title bar, buttons, etc). I dislike .net framework(C#)'s and wxpython's stereotyped and poor GUI frame.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: on what OS should the editor run? what features do you need? Please edit your question and include that. Thanks!

Comment: I think my question contains enough information. Even pictures! But I edited for helping you!

Comment: If you want to modify the titlebar of classic Windows window, I'm not sure how you can do this. I'm thinking about C++ but please ask this at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) to get more information, telling the code you've tried.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!  stackoverflow.com leaded me here. OTL. The head of question should be changed from "which tool" to "how to". thanks.

Comment: If it is a question of how to, then I believe it's more suitable for stackoverflow. If it's a question of "which tool" then it's a question that is suitable for softwarerecs. If you are interested there are GUI libraries for Python that allows you to have a better looking title bar than the default .NET title bar. If you are interested let me know and I will create an answer.